# Do not select an ID if any status = Pending

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset that returns an id and all statuses that are associated with it. The result set is below.

```
id     status
20965     1
20965     3
20965     6
20965     5
```

What I am needing is to not select the id if any status = 5 (pending) or 6 (postponed). I'm sure I'm just not seeing this clearly but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one option using `not exists`:

```
select *
from yourtable y
where not exists (
   select 1
   from yourtable y2
   where y.id = y2.id and y2.status in (5,6)
)
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I knew I was missing the last piece which was in the not exists. Thanks for your help.